# ActiveRecord: How to unscope a default_scope when using left_join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, left-join

Let's say I have a model `Person`. This `Person` has many `Posts`. Posts have a default scope to exclude all soft-deleted entries. Soft-deleted means, that an attribute `deleted_at` is not `nil`.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :posts

end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :person
  default_scope { where(:deleted_at => nil) }

end
```

I now want to query all persons who have at least one post and I want to include soft-deleted posts as well - so I want the default scope not to apply. Using

```
Person.left_joins(:posts).where.not(posts: { id: nil })
```

still applies the default scope and results in this SQL:

```
SELECT `persons`.* FROM `persons` LEFT OUTER JOIN `posts` ON `posts`.`person_id` = `persons`.`id` AND `posts`.`deleted_at` IS NULL WHERE `posts`.`id` IS NOT NULL
```

What is an elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `unscoped` method to remove all previous scopes.

```
Person.unscoped.left_join(....
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped

EDIT: I missunderstood where the default scope was, I think you can unscope the association:

```
has_many :posts, -> { unscoped }
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many

This should unscope the association by default. Not 100% sure though! Hope it helps.

Comment: Ah, no, doesn't work. The default scope isn't on `Person` but on `Post`, the association. The problem is that `unscoped` removes all applied conditions including associations.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way in Rails 5 and it works:

```
has_many :posts, -> { unscope( where: : deleted_at) }
```